# I have an error with the installation of the SSL certificate in Apache

Tags: ubuntu, ssl, certificate

everyone. I have a problem trying to renew the SSL certificate for my website. A few days ago I downloaded the new certificate (.crt, .key and intermediate.crt) and replaced it with the old one (obviously I left it the same names). I reloaded the apache service but it does not work, when I enter my website it keeps telling me that the certificate has expired. Honestly I'm going crazy and can't find the error, I would appreciate your help. This is the content in archive default-ssl.conf

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    <VirtualHost *:443>
            ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
            ServerName sastreriamilitar.mil.ar
            DocumentRoot /var/www/html
           
            ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
            CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

            SSLEngine on
            SSLCertificateFile      /etc/apache2/ssl/sastreriamilitar.mil.ar.crt
            SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/sastreriamilitar.mil.ar.key

            SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/apache2/ssl/SectigoRSADomainValidationSecureServerCA.crt

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Does the certificate fingerprint being served to the client match the certificate fingerprint you are expecting?

Comment: I don't understand your answer. Where can I check that?

Comment: You can view the certificate *thumbprint* and/or serial number through the browser.

Comment: Yes, they match perfectly

Comment: Run `openssl x509 -text -noout -in <crt file>` and check the dates. It's possible, that vh data you posted, is not what apache is actually delivering.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. 
I did what you told me and indeed they both coincide in relation to the same domain. Below I attach the beginning of both.

OLD CERTIFICATE:
        Validity
            Not Before: Oct 27 00:00:00 2020 GMT
            Not After : Oct 27 23:59:59 2021 GMT
        Subject: CN = sastreriamilitar.mil.ar

NEW CERTIFICATE:
        Validity
            Not Before: Oct 29 00:00:00 2021 GMT
            Not After : Oct 29 23:59:59 2022 GMT
        Subject: CN = sastreriamilitar.mil.ar

Comment: If the browser is saying it has expired, then check the cert details within it.

Comment: The certificate that the website shows me is the old one, therefore it shows me that it has expired. However, on the Ubuntu server I have replaced it with the new one.